# Call MATLAB function from Python

Tags: python, matlab

I'am trying to call a MATLAB function using python 3.4 ,so I have installed the engine API as described in the image.
[image: engine API installation]

But when I try to import the the engine in Python it tells me

```
ImportError: No module named 'matlab'.
```

PS: I have installed Python 3.4 (64) and MATLAB version R2015a

Comment: I have been using Spyder3 running Python 3.5 which is wrong when i downgraded to 3.4 ,every thing works fine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been using Spyder3 running Python 3.5 which doesn't work with the engine but when i downgraded to 3.4 ,every thing works fine now (if you face this problem make sure that you are using Python 2.7,3.4  because this worked for me )